# How can I get connection string on auth callbacks in SSH in golang?

Tags: go, ssh

My server config code is:

```
serverConfig := ssh.ServerConfig{
        PublicKeyCallback: func(c ssh.ConnMetadata, pubKey ssh.PublicKey) (*ssh.Permissions, error) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I start a ssh connection with something like `ssh://user@host:port/path`. How can I get `path` part of the ssh connection string in this callback or any other callbacks where I can check user's key/password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSH is not like http where you have `ssh://user@host:port/path`. The format is `user@host:port` indeed but it doesn't require the `ssh://` and path constructs. In your question, `PublicKeyCallback` is using the public keys. If you are doing custom things, do it outside `PublicKeyCallback`.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, already done in this way.